# how to make filtering of aggregation to use index efficiently?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

i have this query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f71a90f/1/0

and i calculate the average of total heartbeats the visitor as given a quote

and i wanna filter the result to bring me only total average heartbeats above 5

the query works with `HAVING` but it runs over all the table and makes it not efficient in the execution plan giving `11 rows (1300 rows in the actual production base code)` while result is only `3 rows`

i have `PRIMARY KEY (id)` and `KEY (docid, heartbeat)` on the tables and do not know what to do to filter it better

```
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.content,
  AVG(hb.heartbeat) AS beats
FROM
  docs d
LEFT JOIN
  heartbeats hb
    ON hb.docid = d.id
GROUP BY
  d.id
HAVING
  beats > 5
ORDER BY
  beats DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, you don't have any `WHERE` clauses. MySQL therefore must examine all rows in both tables to produce the result set your query describes. `HAVING` clauses, because they filter the results of aggregate functions like `AVG()`, don't usually let the query planner avoid scanning tables.

It already makes decent use of your indexes. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4f2b58be64e80ee25f161d8d09f00345) showing the execution plan.